# ImportError: cannot import name goto Python

Tags: python-2.7, pip, importerror, goto

I am using **Python 2.7** version. I used **goto** command in my python code. At the **first** time, while running the code. It throws error -

```
ImportError : No module named goto
```

then I installed **goto** using command

```
sudo pip install goto
```

It is **installed** but it again throws error -

```
ImportError: cannot import name goto
```

then I downloaded **tar.gz folder** from this link http://pydoc.net/Python/goto/0.1.3/

and installed. But **no** success.

**Any help** on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First **remove** all version of goto package from **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/goto***

then **install** goto package from here - http://entrian.com/goto/download.html